# UWP html5 video tag codec

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, win-universal-app, codec

I want to develop a UWP app using video tag of HTML5. Is there any way that video tag can support all types of video files? and not only mp4 and oog? what is the simplest way to do that

Comment: According to [this document](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp), HTML Video only support MP4, WebM and Ogg and not all web browsers support these formats. I didn't tested these formats in a UWP app, but clearly Video tag can not support all types of video files.

Comment: not directly but i guess there must be some codecs to run more type of files ?